# Loader function showing error while returning Uri value

Tags: android, android-loader

Loader function

```
@Override
public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Uri> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    DbLoader abc=new DbLoader(this,uri,values);

    return abc;
}
```

DbLoader function

```
public class DbLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Uri> {
Context context;
Uri uri;
ContentValues values;
public DbLoader(Context context, Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
    this.uri=uri;
    this.values=values;
}

@Override
public Uri loadInBackground() {
    Log.e("TAG","thread running");
  Uri  uriTemp=context.getContentResolver().insert(uri,values);
    return uriTemp;
}
}
```

I am getting error that I am returning data of wrong return type.
I did the same with String while working with loading data from internet and it worked at that time.
What can I do to remove this error?

Exact error message is

```
Incompatible types.
Required:
android.support.v4.content.Loader
<android.net.Uri>
Found:
com.example.asus.test_table.DbLoader
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong `AsyncTaskLoader`. You want to

`import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;` instead of

`import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;`. The former extends `android.support.v4.content.Loader`, the latter does not.

Comment: also I would appreciate it if you could upvote my question